# spark dataframe groupping does not count nulls

Tags: sql, apache-spark, group-by, null, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark DataFrame which is grouped by a column aggregated with a count:

```
df.groupBy('a').agg(count("a")).show

+---------+----------------+
|a        |count(a)        |
+---------+----------------+
|     null|               0|
|      -90|           45684|
+---------+----------------+


df.select('a').filter('aisNull').count
```

returns

```
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res9: Long = 26834
```

which clearly shows that the null values were not counted initially.

What is the reason for this behaviour? I would have expected (if `null`at all is contained in the grouping result) to properly see the counts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `count` applied to a specific column does not count the null-values. If you want to include the null-values, use:

```
df.groupBy('a).agg(count("*")).show
```

Answer (score 4):

> What is the reason for this behaviour?

SQL-92 standard. [In particular](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) (emphasis mine):

> Let T be the argument or argument source of a <set function specification>.

> If COUNT(*) is specified, then the result is the cardinality of T.

> Otherwise, let TX be the single-column table that is the result of applying the <value expression> to each row of T **and eliminating null values**.

> If DISTINCT is specified, then let TXA be the result of eliminating redundant duplicate values from TX. Otherwise, let TXA be
>               TX.

> If the  COUNT is specified, then the
>                 result is the cardinality of TXA.

Answer (score 1):

value_counts(dropna=False) pyspark's equivalent:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.groupBy('a').agg(f.count('*')).orderBy('count(1)',ascending=False).show()
```

Comment: This is very similar to the accepted answer. Pleasse explain in detail which relevant difference the seemingly simple differences make.