# The difference between countDistinct and distinct.count

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Why do I get different outputs for `..agg(countDistinct("member_id") as "count")` and `..distinct.count`?
Is the difference the same as between `select count(distinct member_id)` and `select distinct count(member_id)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.agg(countDistinct("member_id") as "count")
```

returns the number of distinct values of the `member_id` column, ignoring all other columns, while

```
df.distinct.count
```

will count the number of distinct **records** in the DataFrame - where "distinct" means identical in values of *all* columns.

So, for example, the DataFrame:

```
+-----------+---------+
|member_name|member_id|
+-----------+---------+
|          a|        1|
|          b|        1|
|          b|        1|
+-----------+---------+
```

has only one distinct `member_id` value but two distinct records, so the `agg` option would return 1 while the latter would return 2.

Comment: Then please show that in the question... would be useful if you edit the post to add an example of input for which you get two different results. Or at least the schema of the dataframe.

Answer (score 7):

> Why do I get different outputs for ..agg(countDistinct("member_id") as "count") and ..distinct.count?

Because `.distinct.count` is the same:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT member_id FROM table)
```

while `..agg(countDistinct("member_id") as "count")` is

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) FROM table
```

and `COUNT(*)` [uses different rules than `COUNT(column)` when nulls are encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46276492).

Answer (score 1):

**1st command :**

```
DF.agg(countDistinct("member_id") as "count")
```

return the same as that of `select count distinct(member_id) from DF`.

**2nd command :**

```
DF.distinct.count
```

is actually getting distinct records or removing al duplicates from the DF and then taking the count.

Comment: So, technically the outputs should be the same?

Comment: Nope. 1st one is specific to member id column. and the second one is on all the columns.More specifically 2nd one has group by on all the columns where as 1st one has group by on 1 column.