# Python Spark: difference between .distinct().count() and countDistinct()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I recently notice the difference. For example

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count, countDistinct
graduateProgram = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "Masters", "School of Information", "UC Berkeley"),
    (2, "Masters", "EECS", "UC Berkeley"),
    (3, None, "School of Information", "UC Berkeley"),
    (1, "Ph.D.", "EECS", "UC Berkeley")])\
  .toDF("id", "degree", "department", "school")


graduateProgram.select("degree", "department").distinct().show()
```

returns

[image]

While

```
graduateProgram.select(countDistinct("degree", "department")).show()
```

returns

[image]

Why is this happenning? Is it to expected?

Comment: @eliasah mentioned ticket doesn't explain behavior  in the example above.

Comment: it's looks like countDistinct ignores nulls.

Comment: Indeed. `countDistinct` excludes nulls. As per documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345117/null-value-and-countdistinct-with-spark-dataframe?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Rumoku https://stackoverflow.com/a/49903729/3415409