# Spark: lazy action?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, join, memory, lazy-evaluation

I am working on a complex application. From source data, we compute many statistics, eg .

```
val df1 = sourceData.filter($"col1" === "val" and ...)
     .select(...)
     .groupBy(...)
     .min()

val df2 = sourceData.filter($"col2" === "val" and ...)
     .select(...)
     .groupBy(...)
     .count()
```

As the dataframe are grouped on the same columns, the result dataframes are then grouped together:

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("groupCol"), "full_outer")
    .join(df3....) 
    .write.save(...)
```

(in my code this is done in a loop)

This is not performant, the problem is that each dataframe (I have about 30) ends with a action, so in my understanding each dataframe is computed and returned to the driver, which then sends back data to executors to perform the join.

This gives me memory error, I can increase the driver memory but I am looking for a better way of doing it. For ex. if all dataframes were computed only at the end (with the saving of the joined dataframe) I guess that everything would be managed by the cluster.

Is there a way to do a kind of lazy action? Or should I join the dataframes in another way?

Thx

Comment: Actions are executed on the cluster (workers) - that's the whole idea of parallel processing. The results of these actions may end up on the driver which depends on the action - e.g. collect, take,count,min,max,sum and accumulators, or, they result in storage to the external sytsme like HDFS, KUDU, etc. Just to get the picture straight here.

Comment: Is `.select(...)` the same for all queries?  Sounds like `.groupBy(...)` is `groupBy("groupCol")`, right?

Comment: Good read https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html

Comment: @user6910411 you're right, I am selecting the same columns from all dataframe (except the computation result) and groupy by the same columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the code you've shown contains only one action-like operation - `DataFrameWriter.save`. All other components are lazy.

But laziness doesn't really help you here. The biggest problem (assuming no ugly data skew or misconfigured broadcasting) is that the individual aggregations require separate shuffles and expensive subsequent merge.

A naive solution would be to leverage that:

> the dataframe are grouped on the same columns

to shuffle first:

```scala
val groupColumns: Seq[Column] = ???

val sourceDataPartitioned =  sourceData.groupBy(groupColumns: _*)
```

and use the result to compute individual aggregates

```scala
val df1 = sourceDataPartitioned
  ...

val df2 = sourceDataPartitioned
  ...
```

However, this approach is rather brittle and is unlikely to scale in presence large / skewed groups.

Therefore it would be much better to rewrite your code to perform only aggregation. Luckily for you, [standard SQL behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46276492/6910411) is all you need.

Let's start with structuring you code into three element tuples with:

- `_1` being a predicate (the condition you use with `filter`).
- `_2` being a list of `Columns` for which you want to compute aggregates.
- `_3` being an aggregate function.

Where example structure can look this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{count, min}

val ops: Seq[(Column, Seq[Column], Column => Column)] = Seq(
  ($"col1" === "a" and $"col2" === "b", Seq($"col3", $"col4"), count),
  ($"col2" === "b" and $"col3" === "c", Seq($"col4", $"col5"), min)
)
```

Now you compose aggregate expressions using

```
agg_function(when(predicate, column))
```

pattern

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when

val exprs: Seq[Column] = ops.flatMap {
    case (p, cols, f) => cols.map {
      case c => f(when(p, c))
    }
}
```

and use it on the `sourceData`

```scala
sourceData.groupBy(groupColumns: _*).agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*)
```

Add `aliases` when necessary.

Comment: Hi user6910411, after further tests I noticed that: with few data I need to first repartition, otherwise this is very slow and often only one executor is running ; but with more data it works at its best without repartitioning. Indeed with more data your method is really optimized, you saved my month.