# How to use DataFrame.withColumn with a condition

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I want know how to create a new column on the full DataFrame but whose values are based on only a subset of the DataFrame (i.e. some function applied based on a condition).

In this example, I want to create a column that associates each ID with the sum of only positive values in the Value column by ID.

Using this is the dataset:

```
+-----+-----+
|  ID |Value|
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  -4 |
+-----+-----+
|  2  |  5  |
+-----+-----+
|  2  | -23 |
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  5  |
+-----+-----+
|  2  | 19  |
+-----+-----+
|  1  | 12  |
+-----+-----+
```

I'm looking to get the following result:

```
+-----+-----+-------------+
|  ID |Value| sum_pos_val |
+-----+-----+-------------+
|  1  |  -4 |     17      |
+-----+-----+-------------+
|  2  |  5  |     24      |
+-----+-----+-------------+
|  2  | -23 |     24      |
+-----+-----+-------------+
|  1  |  5  |     17      |
+-----+-----+-------------+
|  2  | 19  |     24      |
+-----+-----+-------------+
|  1  | 12  |     17      |
+-----+-----+-------------+
```

The following code will sum the Value column by ID but how can I filter out only positive values to sum over?

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('ID')
df.withColumn('sum_pos_val', f.sum('Value').over(w))\
    .show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```py
f.sum('Value').over(w)
```

with

```py
f.sum(
    f.when(f.col('Value') > 0, f.col('Value')).otherwise(0)
).over(w)
```

or even simpler (see [spark dataframe groupping does not count nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46276219/11003499))

```py
f.sum(
    f.when(f.col('Value') > 0, f.col('Value'))
).over(w)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: What if I want to apply more than one condition? How do I specify and AND or OR statement within f.when()?